# Converting date to datetime object python

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I have a date which I convert into iso format using:

```
#createDate is fetched from a json output of an API  
createDate = device['createDate']

# Convert into iso format
# Sample output value : 2014-11-13T16:23:19+00:00
create_date_utcFormat = dateparser.parse(createDate).astimezone(tz.tzutc()).isoformat()
```

When I try adding this object to DB I get `SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.`  How can I convert `create_date_utcFormat` into datetime object?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you a more generic answer to these kinds of problems. If you are having trouble matching types, two things can really help:

1. Interactive Debugging
2. `type()`

Commit the following to memory:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Putting this line anywhere in your code will pause execution of your script when it reaches that point and drop you to a `(pdb)` prompt, which is similar to the regular python shell, except you can only do one line at a time and there are a few commands available (`c` for continue probably being the most important to know).

From here you can use `type()` to determine what type objects and variables are, and hopefully discover what Daniel said in his answer--that `type(dateparser.parse(createDate).astimezone(tz.tzutc()))` is already a `datetime` object.

Comment: good eye (been a minute since I've wrestled with python date objects), fixed!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out , this is indeed very useful. but I got `TypeError: datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 16, 23, 19, tzinfo=tzutc()) is not JSON serializable` when I tried storing this in a json object.

Answer (score 0):

You had a datetime, but you converted it back to a string with `.isoformat()`. Don't do that.